# How to rotate a 2d line?

Tags: c++

Its a very simple question.
How can i rotate a line by one of its endpoints by the angle rad?

Heres my current code ( I couldnt find a different solution )

```
void displayPlayer() {
    float rad;
    putpixel(x, y, 10);
    if (view > 360)
        view = 0;
    nx = (int)round(x*cos(view) - y*sin(view));
    ny = (int)round(x*sin(view) + y*cos(view));
    rad = (double)view / 180.0 * M_PI;
    line(x, y,nx,ny);
    putpixel(cos(rad)*(x + 10) - sin(rad)*(y + 10), sin(rad)*(x + 10) + cos(rad)*(y + 10), 10);

}
```

Heres a litte visualisation of my result:

[image]

The line is supposed to be 10 px long and keep rotating 360°. Ive indicated its origin with a green line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your `view` as it is not to be in radians as you can see by `if (view > 360)` which indicates degree. And you use it in sin and cos.

Or

It seems to me, your `nx` and `ny` use a rotation matrix which rotates relative to origin [0, 0] with the distance to the origin x and y. If you are going to use that, change x and y to something like x1-x and y1-y with x1 and y1 the point you want to rotate relative to x and y. After doing all that, sum it with x and y at the end again.

```
int dx = x1-x, dy = y1-y;
nx = dx * cos(ang) - dy * sin(ang) + x;
ny = dx * sin(ang) + dy * cos(ang) + y;
```

If you haven't noticed yet, dx and dy is the horizontal and vertical distance from the point of rotation. Not the distance (which you probably want to be 10, see below)

If you already know the distance there is another good approach you can read [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/120538/45668) as it is pretty much the same question. It is simpler and easier if you ask me (Choosen answer). Rather than using something like matrix (You can see my answer there too).